# Firefox plugin to detect server side software?

Tags: firefox, plugins, detection

I remember a plugin that could detect which OS and what programming language was used on the server side. I don't know anymore what the name was. It could be Firebug or something like that, but I can't find the function.

Comment: I use netcraft's website: http://uptime.netcraft.com/. Maybe they have a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug makes it easy to look at the headers send by the Server. But be aware, that server could fake or hide this parts of header, so it does not work always.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Browser Plugin called wappalyzer http://www.wappalyzer.com. if you are using firefox plugins site just search for wappalyzer.